# Spark- Spill disk and Spill memory problem

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am new to spark and working on a logic to join 13 files and write the final file into a blob storage. Input files are in CSV format and output is written as parquet. Out of the 13 files, **file1 is 950mb, file2 is 50mb, file3 is 150mb, file4 is 620mb, file5 is 235mb, file6&7 are less than 1mb, file8 is 70mb and rest all are in kbs**.  No other computation is being performed yet I see 2GB of spill memory.  **How to avoid this memory spill?**

I did some investigation and understood about **AQE** which is by default enabled in latest spark version and AQE takes care of partitioning and coalesce by itself so there is no 200 partitions after a shuffle. In my case the final written file has 13 parquet partitions each around 60mb.

Secondly, I focused on the join types with AQE enabled. I see that AQE does a broadcast on all the joins except for file1, file4 and file5. These three joins are performed with **Sortmerge** join and rest as **BroadcastHash** join. So AQE does its job in choosing the right join. Still memory spill exists.

Next I started to read on how to reduce memory spill. I understood that memory spill happens when the partition size is bigger than what spark memory could handle resulting in spilling data to disk. This spillage happens during the shuffle stage in the join and one suggestion is to avoid shuffle by **bucketing the data**. So I started to bucket  file1, file4 and file5 on join keys (which is same for the 3 files) and distributed them each into 10 buckets. The DAG results showed there is no shuffle this time but **still memory spill exits** with same size.

I am unable to reduce this memory spillage after many tries with different bucket sizes. I understand that my files are not that big but this is one month data and my downstream applications will process much bigger files as I add more monthly data to it.

I am using standard_D3_v2 with 14GB & 4 cores with worker range as 2-8. This join operation on 13 files uses 6 workers where only 2 workers are used till end of join phase and for writing the output file it uses 4 more workers (observed this based on event timeline).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to avoid this spillage in memory?

Comment: since you're new to Spark, and this might be a bit overkill, but try to **disable** AQE, then lower down `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` (which is 128Mb by default, which is larger than half of your files). After this change, you'll notice the larger partition for each dataframe (i.e. `df.getNumPartitions()`). Of course, you'd have to control 200 shuffle now, by changing `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`. Give it a try.

Comment: btw, appreciate your effort of investigation, pretty impressive

Comment: Ya, this looks like a kill. I am not sure if I have to focus much on spills at this point. Anyways, I tried disabling AQE and reduced shuffle partition between 15-20 and  reduced the maxPartitionBytes to 60Mb. Still there is spillage of the same amount.

Comment: Increasing the executor memory to 58GB from 14GB solved the problem. But I see 4 extra executors were added 2 minutes after my job got completed.  This means Instead of paying for 14GB cluster I am going to pay for 56GB cluster which is going to add some cost. I can even ignore the spill for now, but is it possible to run this job without spillage using a 14GB cluster?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid spilling, you could either (or both) :

1. Increase the partitions number (increase default parallelism). You will get smaller parquet files as a collateral effect.
2. Increase executor memory (and/or reduce number of cores per executors)

Comment: I increased the executor configuration from 14GB-4 cores to 28GB-8 cores. Still spillage exists but it was reduced by half. Then further I increased it to 56Gb-16cores and there is no spillage in the workflow. The entire process used only 2 executors and produced many small files (a total of 37) and 37 task is visible in the last spark job. 

But, after completing the write process I see 4 more executors were added to the flow. This happened 2 minutes after completing the final job. This is strange!

Comment: I think I did the 2nd option as you suggested or do you mean increase executor memory fraction for every executors?

Comment: Plz read carefully. Dont increase number of cores but reduce them.

Comment: I used the basic version with 4 cores (D3_V2) so I cannot decrease them beyond the 4 cores.  Do you mean run the jobs with only 2 executors and no auto-scaling?

Comment: When you say increase executor memory, do you mean increase executor memory fraction as in the diagram [here](https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/) ?